# Voronoi texture Eevee rendering problems with 2.81

Tags: texturing, eevee-render-engine

I am having problems with Voronoi texture node on Eevee after the new update (2.81). It is working fine on Cycles and older versions of Blender (Cycles and Eevee on 2.80)

[image]

Comment: [don't confirm on 2.81.16](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1i_E-KWCtOmJmYt7DRCjxiIUSf5Ls0u-Q) how do other procedural textures behave in eevee? have you tried factory reset blender?

Comment: When I import it to an older version, it automatically adds a math node (multiply), so it seems there is some kind of way to convert to new Voronoi that I don't understand

Comment: The rest of procedural textures are OK

Comment: Same situation on 2.82 alpha

Comment: Has this been fixed|? I am using blender through Steam and have the same problem.

Comment: I ended up replacing my laptop to something with decent GPU. Do you have Intel or built-in graphics card?